# Java Google Cloud Endpoints tutorial api not appearing in viewer

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm just starting to learn endpoints so I am following along with the Java tutorial on the app engine website.  I'm writing the get method [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/write_api) but at the part where I run the server and visit `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer` nothing shows up.  It says that the Dev App Server is running fine and I have copied and pasted the code directly.  Where do I start finding out what is wrong? Thanks

Edit: It also seems to not be showing me the api when I use the eclipse plugin to auto generate the backend.

Comment: Do you get an entirely blank page, or does it appear to be stuck loading? Are you using Chrome or another browser?

Answer (score 0):

did you try the [tic tac toe](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java) example from Google? I had the same issue. However, for me it was patience, after a minute or 2, the API showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis`

I also got the same problem when I was following the official tutorial. Later I found the answer from here: [RESTful CRUD APIs with AppEngine, Cloud Endpoints and Dart code generation](http://blog.dartwatch.com/2013/06/restful-crud-apis-with-appengine-cloud.html)